# How to get the name of internal Bluetooth adapter

Tags: usb, bluetooth, mint, adapter

How can I get the name of my laptop's internal Bluetooth adapter?

```
lsusb | grep Bluetooth
```

shows nothing, but I can use it and it's working.

Comment: Do you want the manufacturer and product info or do want to know what will be displayed on another device scanning for discoverable bluetooth devices?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Bluetooth devices are not always listed as "Bluetooth" in `lsusb`.

In most cases, Bluetooth adapters use the USB interface. You can run `lsusb` and look for it there. The word "Bluetooth" may be there or may not.

Also in many cases laptops have combined Wi-Fi/Bluetooth chips.

So most likely you will get the required information by running:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
```

This way you will get the ID of your Wi-Fi adapter and the list of your USB devices.